# Auto Hot Key SendKey Not Working

Tags: autohotkey, sendkeys

So I have this:

```
#SingleInstance, force

^x::ControlSend, , abc, notepad.exe
```

and it doesn't work. I have notepad open, and I hit `control+x` in the Windows Explorer and nothing happens. It doesn't cut the file I have selected or type abc into the notepad window. Is something wrong with the syntax? I double checked everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [win title](http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm) documentation.

AutoHotkey interprets "notepad.exe" as "some window with the title 'notepad.exe'". Unless you have opened a document called so, the specified window will not be found.

Use `..., ahk_exe notepad.exe` instead.

all the best,

Comment: Oh!! `ahk_exe`! I knew I was missing *something*...I'll run this through as soon as I can. I checked the documentation before posting, but I couldn't find the part about the `ahk_???` Thanks!

Comment: Oh wait. I mean I checked the `ControlSend` documentation and couldn't find anything about the `wintitle`.